# Is an unseen character in phone call (V.O.) or (O.S.)?

Tags: screenwriting, script, scriptwriting

Is an unseen character in phone call (V.O.) or (O.S.)?
I don’t understand if it’s considered a voice over or an offscreen

Comment: O.S. What do you not understand?

Comment: Are VO and OS interchangeable?

Comment: No, they're not. Did you do research? Try searching for diegesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A character that is off screen speaks from *off screen*.

*Voice over* refers to a n̲a̲r̲r̲a̲t̲o̲r̲ who narrates the story (e.g. in a documentary, where the narrator never appears in the film).